# Evitando quebra de linhas em text areas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho um textarea normal

```
<textarea placeholder=" Digite aqui" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

Queria que quando o usuário pressionasse enter, ele não quebrasse linha e sim já enviasse o conteúdo.

Poderia fazer isso com um `input`? sim
Mas o problema é que eu quero que tenha uma quebra de linha só quando o usuário acabe digitando de mais (chegue no fim daquela linha).

Alguém sabe se tem como?

Comment: Faz um Javascript pra isso ué.

Comment: **Se não quer quebra de texto, use um `<input type="text">`!!!**

Comment: Naldson, a resposta que você marcou como correta está na verdade **incorreta**. Sugiro revisar sua escolha. Pense nas pessoas que vão sofrer depois tentando usar esse código que não funciona.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como está usando Bootstrap, o exemplo abaixo utiliza jQuery.

```
var ENTER_KEY = 13;

$('textarea').on('keypress', function(event) {
  var char = event.which || event.keyCode;
  if (char == ENTER_KEY) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('form').submit();
  }
})
```

Não coloquei como *snippet* pois o StackOverflow bloqueia, mas você pode ver funcionando no [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rnbr/6e3zmmz8/).

Se quiser manter a quebra de linha quando o usuário pressionar <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> pode fazer a checagem com [**`mouveEvent#shiftKey()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/shiftKey) que retorna `true` se o *shift* estiver pressionado:

```
var ENTER_KEY = 13;

$('textarea').on('keypress', function(event){
    var char = event.which || event.keyCode;

    if(char == ENTER_KEY){
       event.preventDefault();
       if(event.shiftKey){
           $(this).val($(this).val() + '\n'); // shift + enter = Quebra linha
           return;
       }
       $(this).parent('form').submit(); // somente o Enter = Envia o form
    }
});
```

Exemplo online no [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rnbr/6e3zmmz8/3/).

#### API:

- [**`parent()`**](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)
- [**`submit()`**](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)
- [**`on()`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [**`event#preventDefault()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/event/preventDefault)

Comment: Ou melhor, por que não avisa "Pressione Shift+Enter para pular linha" na página, que ai o form não vai ser enviado!

Comment: O seu do mesmo jeito quando pressiona enter, o form é enviado.

Comment: Cara, agora quando eu pressiono enter, ele não quebra linha... Blz... Mas ele ainda não está enviando

Comment: @Nathan1302 porque na pergunta não pede isso ^^

Comment: @Naldson ué, você disse que queria que o formulário fosse enviado ao pressionar enter. É pra enviar ou quebrar linha? [Edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/105029/edit) sua pergunta com todas as informações.

Comment: Foi isso que eu falei @renan ele falou 2 coisas confusas!

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi ele quer que quebra a linha, sem precisar apertar enter e quando apertar enter enviar o form !?!?

Comment: Oque eu quis dizer era.... Quando ele apertasse enter. Não quebrasse a linha e sim enviasse logo a mensagem. No caso a linha só ia ser quebrada quando o usuário chegasse ao fim dela..... Um exemplo é esse textarea que eu estou digitando agora. ele faz exatamente isso xD

Comment: Juntei sua resposta com a do @P.Calixto e deu tudo certo...

Comment: @Naldson bacana que você aceitou uma resposta que nem funciona, mas ok.

Comment: @Nathan1302 saquei. Vou colocar um exemplo com shift para outras pessoas que encontrarem essa resposta, thanks.

Comment: Sim, por que eu acho que mesmo que pressione enter com o `preventDefault()` eu creio que ele vai continuar enviando o form. Eu acho que ele quer que quando chegue no final da textarea ele quebre a linha automáticamente.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando javascript, basta manipular o evento `onkeypress` do `textarea`, verificar se a tecla pressionada é o `enter` e realizar o submit do form ou qualquer outra coisa que desejar.

```
document.getElementById('meuTextarea')
  .addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (key === 13) {
      e.preventDefault(); //Evitar a quebra de linha (remove o comportamento padrão)
      document.getElementById("myForm").submit(); //Submeter o formulário
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Segue outra opção em jquery https://jsfiddle.net/PauloKlixto/sc9z66hh/embedded/result/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#teste" ).keypress(function() {
   if(event.keyCode == 13){
     $( "#myform" ).submit();
   }
  });
});
```

Comment: Esse código nem funciona pois `event` é undefined.

Comment: Podes dar uma revisão a esta resposta?

Comment: Para os futuros visitantes, esta resposta pode não funcionar (talvez funcione no IE já que `event` é um objeto válido lá). Aqui está um versão ligeiramente modificada do fiddle que pelo menos faz o que foi prometido: https://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/sc9z66hh/7/. Entretanto sugiro olhar as outras respostas que estão mais completas.

Comment: Obrigado pela edição.